# python argparse how to get entire command as string

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a script named `patchWidth.py` and it parses command line arguments with `argparse`:

```
# read command line arguments -- the code is able to process multiple files
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='angle simulation trajectories')
parser.add_argument('filenames', metavar='filename', type=str, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-vec', metavar='v', type=float, nargs=3)
```

Suppose this script is run with the following:

```
>>> python patchWidth.py file.dat -vec 0. 0. 1.
```

Is there a way to get this entire thing as a string in python? I would like to be able to print to the output file what command was run with what arguments.

Comment: `parser.parse_args()` parses `sys.argv[1:]` and uses `sys.argv[0]` as the `prog` attribute in `usage`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use the sys module:

```
import sys
str(sys.argv) # arguments as string
```

Note that `argv[0]` is the script name. For more information, take a look at the [sys module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Answer (score 11):

I do not know if it would be the best option, but...

```
import sys

" ".join(sys.argv)
```

Will return a string like `/the/path/of/file/my_file.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Comment: I wanted to remove the first parameter, so I did a .remove() on the first in the list first then did the join. Worked great for my use case of grabbing all words after the first.

Answer (score 4):

This will work with commands that have space-separated strings in them.

```
import sys
" ".join("\""+arg+"\"" if " " in arg else arg for arg in sys.argv)
```

Sample output:

```
$ python3 /tmp/derp.py "my arg" 1 2 3
python3 /tmp/derp.py "my arg" 1 2 3
```

This won't work if there's a string argument with a quotation mark in it, to get around that you'd have to delimit the quotes like: `arg.replace("\"", "\\\"")`. I left it out for brevity.

Comment: This is true so +1, but it will fail if the quotes are single quotes. and what if you have intermixed but an improvement would be `(" ".join(shlex.quote(arg) if " " in arg else arg for arg in sys.argv))`   so `import shlex` to escape the single quotes